# Oracle upgrade doesn't work for non-admin user

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracleclient

I'm upgrading Oracle Client (12 -> 19) and SqlDeveloper (4 -> 21). However, when a regular user tries to start the new SqlDeveloper, the cursor says it's busy for a second, but then nothing happens.

What are some things I can check to see what is happening?

Comment: There is no 'upgrade' for SQL Developer. You simply download the new version, unzip it, and run the EXE. You can say 'yes' to importing your settings from the older copy you have. If that doesn't work, then we need to start troubleshooting. Are you Windows, Mac, or Linux?

Comment: Be that as it may, the exe for v 21 does nothing. The cursor spins for a second - the end; no program, no error, no service, no log (that I know of).

Comment: I can't help you if you don't tell me what OS you're on - my debug steps differ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the executable from the console (don't run it from the start menu or an icon on the desktop); then you will be able to see what the error messages are that prevent it from running and the error messages will stay visible in the console (rather than briefly appearing for a fraction of a second and then disappearing as the application closes). Then when you know what the error is, you can find a solution.